# R dplyr, problem renaming values based on a value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I'm not sure what is wrong with this mutate function. When using this line of code, it doesn't change the values to the wanted values.

```
dataADstudies_1639_5cols <- dataADstudies_1639_5cols_2D %>%
  mutate(Activity = if_else(Parameter == grepl('ANT_L', Parameter), "Phot_Ant_TL", Activity))
```

My df looks like this:

```
    Nr      Section Activity    Parameter       Value
44  1639_1  Day 0   Photo_2D    ANT_L_Ery       18.932
45  1639_1  Day 0   Photo_2D    ANT_L_EryRat    1.189
46  1639_1  Day 0   Photo_2D    ANT_L_Rough     9.552
47  1639_1  Day 0   Photo_2D    ANT_NL_Ery      0.583
48  1639_1  Day 0   Photo_2D    ANT_NL_EryRa    0.886
49  1639_1  Day 0   Photo_2D    ANT_NL_Rough    3.958
```

I want to recode values in the activity column to Phot_Ant_TL when the parameter value contains ANT_L and subsequently change values in the activity column to Phot_Ant_NL when the parameter value contains ANT_NL but I think I need a separate line of code for that

Desired result:

```
    Nr      Section Activity    Parameter       Value
44  1639_1  Day 0   Phot_Ant_TL ANT_L_Ery       18.932
45  1639_1  Day 0   Phot_Ant_TL ANT_L_EryRat    1.189
46  1639_1  Day 0   Phot_Ant_TL ANT_L_Rough     9.552
47  1639_1  Day 0   Phot_Ant_NL ANT_NL_Ery      0.583
48  1639_1  Day 0   Phot_Ant_NL ANT_NL_EryRa    0.886
49  1639_1  Day 0   Phot_Ant_NL ANT_NL_Rough    3.958
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `grepl` like this -

```
library(dplyr)

dataADstudies_1639_5cols <- dataADstudies_1639_5cols_2D %>%
  mutate(Activity = case_when(grepl('ANT_L', Parameter) ~ "Phot_Ant_TL", 
                              grepl('ANT_NL', Parameter) ~ "Phot_Ant_NL", 
                              TRUE ~ Activity))

dataADstudies_1639_5cols
#      Nr Section    Activity    Parameter  Value
#1 1639_1    Day0 Phot_Ant_TL    ANT_L_Ery 18.932
#2 1639_1    Day0 Phot_Ant_TL ANT_L_EryRat  1.189
#3 1639_1    Day0 Phot_Ant_TL  ANT_L_Rough  9.552
#4 1639_1    Day0 Phot_Ant_NL   ANT_NL_Ery  0.583
#5 1639_1    Day0 Phot_Ant_NL ANT_NL_EryRa  0.886
#6 1639_1    Day0 Phot_Ant_NL ANT_NL_Rough  3.958
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
dataADstudies_1639_5cols_2D <- structure(list(Nr = 
c("1639_1", "1639_1", "1639_1", "1639_1", 
"1639_1", "1639_1"), Section = c("Day0", "Day0", "Day0", "Day0", 
"Day0", "Day0"), Activity = c("Photo_2D", "Photo_2D", "Photo_2D", 
"Photo_2D", "Photo_2D", "Photo_2D"), Parameter = c("ANT_L_Ery", 
"ANT_L_EryRat", "ANT_L_Rough", "ANT_NL_Ery", "ANT_NL_EryRa", 
"ANT_NL_Rough"), Value = c(18.932, 1.189, 9.552, 0.583, 0.886, 
3.958)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: All right this solves the recoding. How can I make sure the NAs don't occur and the old values are kept?

Comment: To keep the original values from `Activity` column see the updated answer @tevk .

Answer (score 0):

with case_when instead of if_else and substr instead of grepl it works:

```
dataADstudies_1639_5cols <- dataADstudies_1639_5cols_2D %>%
  mutate(Activity = case_when(substr(Parameter, 1 , 6) == "ANT_NL" ~ "Phot_Ant_NL", 
  T ~ "Phot_Ant_TL"))`
```